# cforest function in R

Tags: r

Is there an argument under the function cforest in R that can make it study the least common observation?

I'm trying to make a grade prediction between 1-5. In my training data I have a lot of observation between 2-4, and some are 1 or 5. random forest is predicating only 2-4, even though I know there's also supposed to be predictions that are 1 and 5.

Thanks!

Comment: If `1` and `5` are rare within the training set, there is an overall small a priori chance that the result will be `1` or `5`. Maybe the forest is correct in never predicting these  from the beginning? You might consider overrepresenting `1` and `5` cases in the training set by putting them twice or n times in the training set, if it is a necessity that they are sometimes predicted.

Comment: there is no argument  under the cforest function that can somehow do that?

Comment: Have you read the function description? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/partykit/versions/1.2-13/topics/cforest There is an argument `weights`. I assume that could be helpfull in giving more weight to the observations leading to `1` and `5`. A minimal reproducible example might convince users to answer with code.